# Visual Studio crashes when adding service reference with Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Tags: .net

Getting below exception when adding service reference:

```
    Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
    Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1026, time stamp: 0x53b50961
    Exception code: 0xc00000fd
    Fault offset: 0x00001b67
    Faulting process id: 0x1734
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d0b86fc763ca2a
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Report Id: 0b7c1d39-2465-11e5-be25-00270e0fc056
```

Comment: With VS215 almost released, using something as old as 2010 seems outdated. Can you reproduce this behaviour with either VS2012 or VS2013?

Comment: @nvoigt: And what if the company wont upgrade it? You can't use Community editions in the enterprise... We still stuck on VS2010 too.

Comment: @leppie *"Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms provided with each product."*

Comment: @nvoigt: No source control, crippled solutions, no thanks ;p I have tried in the past to use it, but it is limited to very specific domains. Also, to have 3 versions installed to just do say a solution with web, winforms and winphone is a complete PITA. That said, I mainly have to use Eclipse now which is way worse... :*(

Comment: Hi from when you get this error log? I have also same problem while adding service reference, my visual studio crash and restarts, i can't find error log, can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if .net framework version 4.5 is installed on the machine, it solved the problem for me. :-)

Comment: Thanks..  I install 4.5.2 framework and it resolved my problem... :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think your Visual Studio has some files missing...

Just Run Visual studio Setup and Select the Repair Option...It will replicate the issue...

Hope works fine...:)